# Why does a sticky piston powered by a redstone block through another sticky piston from the top not contract?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm working on a little redstone project and I've stumbled upon this difficulty.

If I activate the lever the top sticky gets powered as expected. Deactivating the lever pulls the top sticky piston with the redstone block and retracts the bottom one. **However** the bottom piston activates immediately again so it is stuck in this position! Even if I remove the redstone block it stays like that! I have to put a solid nonpowered block above it to get it to contract.

First of: Why does this happen?

Secondly: Is there any way to get the bottom sticky piston to retract? I have just the block above it available in the redstone contraption I'm trying to build.

Observation: If I build exactly the same thing but on flat ground (powering the bottom sticky from a side), this does not happen and the thing functions as I would expect. (second screenshot)

Another observation: If I try to power the sticky from the bottom nothing even happens upon deactivation of the lever!

Any help greatly appreciated!

[image: bad redstone contraption]
badly functioning (bottom piston retracting and then activating immediately)

[image: good redstone contraption]
perfectly fine

[image: really bad redstrone contraption]
not functioning at all; upon deactivation of the lever nothing happens